# Find error when error message doesn't show location

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, webpack, zone.js

I'm building an app using Ionic, Angular, and Firebase.

I'm having a problem where the code is being built and packaged by webpack and it returns an error from `polyfills.js`, which is not useful in the slightest...

The error message looks like this:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Missing Command Error ; Zone: <root> ; Task:
Promise.then ; Value: Missing Command Error undefined
```

[image]

The error happens every 30ish seconds.

And the non-minifed version of the error looks like this:

```
function l(t) {
    var e = t.prototype,
        n = e.then;
    e[d] = n;
    var r = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(t.prototype, "then");
    r && !1 === r.writable && r.configurable && Object.defineProperty(t.prototype, "then", {
            writable: !0
        }),
        t.prototype.then = function(t, e) {
            var r = this;
            return new x(function(t, e) {
                n.call(r, t, e)
            }).then(t, e)
        },
        t[R] = !0
}
var h = n.symbol,
    p = [],
    v = h("Promise"),
    d = h("then");
n.onUnhandledError = function(t) {
        if (n.showUncaughtError()) {
            var e = t && t.rejection;
            e ? console.error("Unhandled Promise rejection:", e instanceof Error ? e.message : e, "; Zone:", t.zone.name, "; Task:", t.task && t.task.source, "; Value:", e, e instanceof Error ? e.stack : void 0) : console.error(t)
        }
    },
    n.microtaskDrainDone = function() {
        for (; p.length;)
            for (; p.length;)
                ! function() {
                    var t = p.shift();
                    try {
                        t.zone.runGuarded(function() {
                            throw t
                        })
                    } catch (t) {
                        r(t)
                    }
                }()
    };
```

Any idea how I would debug this? Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you have handled rejection in your promise or not

Comment: @MukulSharma That doesn't really make sense to me... which promise? How would I find that

Comment: As per error shown it seems somewhere you have used promise in your code but it's not handeled properly.

Comment: @MukulSharma I understand, but that's like finding a needle in a haystack.. I don't know which promise it is